# How to create image paths which contain spaces?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In Sphinx, I am trying to include images from a subdirectory.

While this works for paths without spaces such as

```
.. image:: imagepath/image.png
```

I am not successful for paths with spaces.

What I have tried is:

```
.. image:: imagepath with space/image.png
.. image:: `imagepath with space/image.png`
.. image::`imagepath with space/image.png`
```

What am I missing? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: From http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#images : `Note that image file names should not contain spaces.`. I am afraid it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a simpler way, but at least, it is possible to replace a space with backslash space:

```
.. figure:: imagepath\ with\ space/image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to include image paths which contain spaces. You will have to rename those image files.

Comment: It is possible indeed